# How to add shape file in map using arcgis javascript even if shape file exceeded the maximum number of records allowed i.e 1000

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I am new to arcgis.I am referring documentation of arcgis javascript 3.19 API.I have taken example from that documentation for adding shape file but when I added zip file which contains .shx,.mdf etc file it gives me error like "The maximum number of records allowed (1000) has been exceeded".

Answer (score 4):

> Limitations
>
> - Files containing more than 1,000 features cannot be added to a map

it's a limitation according to the documentation [shapefiles](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm)

Link found on the sample app [Add Shapefile](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/portal_addshapefile/)

How about spliting your file to <1000 shapes ?

Comment: I read that document but I want to know is it possible to add  shape file which has greater than 1000 shapes?